# Implementing Button Fill Effect from Entered Side in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a button with a fill effect in ReactJS, where the fill originates from the side where the cursor enters the button. An example of the desired effect can be seen on the [ronasit.com](https://ronasit.com/) website, specifically the "Estimate Project" button in the header.

I've attempted to achieve this using CSS, but I'm having difficulty getting the fill effect to start from the entered side. Instead, it fills from the center, which is not the behavior I'm looking for.

I'm looking for guidance on how to implement this fill effect using ReactJS and CSS, ensuring that the fill originates from the side where the cursor enters the button. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

[image: no fill]

[image: filling]

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It doesn't look that much different than the simple hover cursor they're doing for the whole page. Basically an absolute element under the cursor, styled to a specific width+border/"radius", and then zindex'd into the background of the button being hovered over. The secondary dot just has a larger "radius".

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the button, you will see this element inside.

```
<span class="button_fill button_button_fill__DfSkP button_button_fill_primary__yN6Sr" style="left: 183.388px; top: 47.6908px;"></span>
```

It is basically an absolute-positioned shape (most likely a circle) with `scale: 0` at first. When the button is hovered, the cursor offset with respect to the button is calculated in JS and assigned to the circle as the absolute top/left values. Then the circle is scaled up and moved to the center of the button with a transition.

You may want to check `offsetX`, `offsetY` properties of **MouseEvent** to programmatically write the behavior: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX

You can observe the behavior in the inspect window, inside the `Elements > Styles` tab.